# jquery click drop down slide toggle navigation

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation, toggle

I've been trying to figure this out for ages. Basically I have a menu and when a user clicks on an arrow it will slideToggle the dropdown below.

I'd like it to do a number of things.

1) When the user clicks on the arrow dropdown and it slides down I'd like them to be able to click on the arrow again and for the dropdown menu to slide up.

2) If a user clicks a different arrow dropdown I'd like the first dropdown to disappear and then the new dropdown to appear.

This is what I have so far. It's working apart from point 2.

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {  
    $('nav li i.open').find('.dropdown').not($(this)).slideToggle(300);
    $('nav li').find('.open').not($(this)).removeClass('open');    
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent('nav li').find('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
});
```

You can see a jsfiddle here which hopefully shows its a bit better (the red box is the clickable area):

http://jsfiddle.net/c8kHN/1/

EDIT:
I've managed to get the second point to work (first dropdown to disappear if a user clicks on another one) - however it then breaks the first point.

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {  
    $('nav li.open').not($(this)).find('.dropdown').hide();
    $('nav').find('.open').not($(this)).removeClass('open');    
    $(this).parent('nav li').toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent('nav li').find('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8kHN/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you collect the child "i" that is clicked it helps later to decide which "div" to show/hide. Your code could benefit from adding different classes to the li's, but I wrote an answer without adding anything to your original HTML. hope this helps.

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {

var child = $(this).index('nav ul li i');

if ($(this).siblings('.dropdown').is(":visible")){
    $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
}else{
    $('.dropdown').slideUp(300);
    $('.dropdown:eq('+child+')').slideDown(300);    
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you this worked wonderfully!

I managed to do it using: http://jsfiddle.net/c8kHN/8/

but I think your solution is a lot more elegant - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this code

```
$('nav li i').click(function() {  
    $('nav li i.open').find('.dropdown').not($(this)).slideToggle(300);
    $('nav li').find('.open').not($(this)).removeClass('open');    
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
    $(this).parent('nav li').find('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Hope this is you looking for..